# Create Program with python to Change Caps Lock in Windows Like in MacOS

Tags: python, windows, macos, capslock

I want to make Program with python for change My normal Caps Lock in Windows can do the same think in MacOS.

Features
-Press Caps Lock to switch language keyboard. ( Keyboard Layout )
-Hold Caps Lock 1000ms to turn on/off Caps Lock.

I new in python, I think about concept it will work like this.

```
// sudo code
keyboard // keyboard event
keyboard.press // keyboard key press

while (true) // loop for check all the time
{
  if (keyboard.press === 'Caps Lock') { // if press Caps Lock
    n = 0; // create variable
    while (keyboard.press === 'Caps Lock' && n < 1000) { // if press/hold Caps Lock
      delay(1) // delay 1 ms
      n++ // n = n + 1
    }
    // when release key / hold longer 1000ms
    if ( n < 1000 ) {
      // switch language keyboard. ( Keyboard Layout )
    } else {
      // toggle Caps Lock.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I use AutoHotKey to switch keyboard language ( Keyboard layout )

I have 2 options.

Option 1.
This Script ***Press Caps Lock*** to switch Layout but
***Press Shift + Caps Lock*** to toggle Caps Lock

For use with Auto Hot Key Script *V1*

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

sel := 0

#if (sel=0)
capslock::
  send {lwin down}{Space}
  sel := 1
return
#if

capslock up::
  send {lwin up}
  sel := 0
return
```

For use with Auto Hot Key Script *V2*

```
SendMode "Input"
SetWorkingDir A_ScriptDir

sel := 0
CapsLock:: {
  if sel = 0 {
    Send "{LWin Down}{Space}"
    global sel := 1
  }
}
CapsLock Up:: {
  Send "{LWin Up}"
  global sel := 0
}
```

Option 2.
This Script ***Press Caps Lock*** to switch Layout but
***Hold Caps Lock*** for 0.5 Second to toggle Caps Lock

*Win + Space can use only windows 8/8.1/10/11*

Cr. : https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=95338&fbclid=IwAR1PGe0NfvkfFvvJGkBe89OoLMPQCCsOvm2kELEIkXczRFqcmfbN1ms3txI

For use with Auto Hot Key Script *V1*

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

$CapsLock::
KeyWait, CapsLock, T0.5
If ErrorLevel
{
    if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") = 0
    SetCapsLockState on
    else 
    SetCapsLockState off
    Keywait, CapsLock
}
else Send {lWinDown}{Space}{lWinUp} 
Return
```